# Как открыть большой XML файл?

Tags: xml, php

Как открыть большой XML файл на PHP?  
Файл 250Мб.

Comment: Что именно мешает его открыть, помимо естественных ограничений на время и память?

Comment: Может само его выполнение по временн?

Comment: `$h = fopen("<большой_файл_на_250мегабайт>.xml", r);`  
а в чем проблема у ТС? :)

Comment: а как именно нужно открыть? может sax подойдет?

Answer (score 1):

В PHP есть специальные средства - [XMLReader](https://www.php.net/XMLReader)